# Create two vertical ListBox with visibility

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need two create two list: list1 and list2 in list1 I have orders list, if I select an order the order articles must displays in list2.
Any idea to do that?
[image]

Create two vertical ListBox with visibility

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is a master-detail view, see:

- [How to: Use the Master-Detail Pattern with Hierarchical Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-use-the-master-detail-pattern-with-hierarchical-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Since you do not provide an example, let us assume a **very minimal** one using the MVVM pattern. Be sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view models to enable updating bindings in the user interface when properties change.

This is the orders type, which has an order `Id` and a collection of `Article`s.

```
public class Order
{
   public Order(string id, ObservableCollection<Article> articles)
   {
      Articles = articles;
      Id = id;
   }

   public string Id { get; }

   public ObservableCollection<Article> Articles { get; }
}
```

This is the article type, it has a `Name`.

```
public class Article
{
   public Article(string name)
   {
      Name = name;
   }

   public string Name { get; }
}
```

In the main view model for the view, you would expose a collection of `Order`s (I assume a shopping cart). You need to create an instance of the view model an assign it as data context of your view, either in code-behind or in XAML as shown later below.

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
   public ShoppingCartViewModel()
   {
      Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>
      {
         new Order("Order 1", new ObservableCollection<Article>
         {
            new Article("Article 1.1"),
            new Article("Article 1.2"),
            new Article("Article 1.3"),

         }),
         new Order("Order 2", new ObservableCollection<Article>
         {
            new Article("Article 2.1"),
            new Article("Article 2.2"),
            new Article("Article 2.3"),

         })
      };
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; }
}
```

The view is a `Window` with a `Grid`, which hosts two `TextBlock`s as headline and two `ListBox`es, one for the `Order`s, one for the `Article`s. The property [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is set to `true`, so the the currently selected `Order` is tracked in the view. The second `ListBox` binds the `Articles` collection of the current item in the `Orders` collection with [the `/` binding syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-path-syntax).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.ShoppingCartView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShoppingCartView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
       <local:ShoppingCartViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
   <Border Margin="10">
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Orders" TextAlignment="Center"/>
         <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" DisplayMemberPath="Id" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Articles" TextAlignment="Center"/>
         <ListBox Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders/Articles}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
</Window>
```

That's it, a simple master-details view that looks like this:

[image: Master-details view: In the top half orders are shown in a ListBox. In the bottom half, the articles of the selected order are shown in a ListBox.]